# how is a blank wallplate attached to drywall

Tags: electrical, drywall, junction-box

Are blank wall plates normally attached directly to a drywall with screws, or it has to be fixed to electrical box?

Comment: What are you trying to cover? Perhaps you want a spring loaded access panel? (electrical-panel probably isn't the right tag)

Comment: Blank electrical wallplates screw to the junction box with the screws provided. Make sure the package still has its screws at the store and someone didn't steal them.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways they're commonly installed, any of which can be considered "normal":

- To a standard or old-work electrical box
- To a low-voltage bracket or frame
- To hollow-wall anchors in the drywall or concrete